# How to display continuation of task records sent from SingleEmailMessage using apex html

Tags: apex, batch, html, singleemailmessage

How to display continuation of task records sent from SingleemailMessage using apex html.

I have sent email with task records using batch in html table, need to send 50 tas records per email but need to split it to another email (send another email) if it exceed 50 records. Let say if there are 500 records, recipient should received 10 emails.

I am not and will not be using VF page.

I have tried to search but did not find any resources to start with.

```
       global class BatchTasksReminders implements 
              Database.Batchable<sObject>, Database.Stateful 
           {
             /*Start method of batch. Get Users as per the 
                  Membership Filters*/
                   global Database.QueryLocator 
             start(Database.BatchableContext BC) {
            String query = 'SELECT Id, Name, Email FROM User 
           WHERE Membership__c = \' 1 Week Reminder\'';
                  return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
              }
        /*It will get the Users as per the Membership Filters 
        and get the Tasks as per the Business Logic and get 
        its related Cases and generate Table to send the 
           User*/
       global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, 
        List<User> userList) {
        Set<String> subjectFilters = new Set<String>{' 1st 
         Response',' Request for Info'};
    List<Task> listofTasks = [SELECT Id, WhatId, Subject, 
    ActivityDate FROM Task WHERE Subject IN: 
      subjectFilters AND Status != 'Completed' AND 
      ActivityDate =: System.Today().addDays(+7) AND 
       What.Type = 'Case' AND RecordType.Name =: 
        'RemindersTask'];
        System.debug('listofTasks'+listofTasks);
        Set<Id> casesIds = new Set<Id>();
         for(Task notCompletedTask : listofTasks){
          if(notCompletedTask.WhatId != null){
            casesIds.add(notCompletedTask.WhatId);
              }
         }
           System.debug('casesIds'+casesIds);
          Map<Id, Case> allCasesMap = new Map<Id, Case>. 
         ();
               if(!casesIds.isEmpty()){
                Set<String> caseRecordTypes = new 
               Set<String>.          
            {'AB','BD','FD','Registration','Rules'};
        allCasesMap = new Map<Id, Case>([SELECT Id, 
         CaseNumber, Subject, ContactId, Contact.Name, 
         Sub_Product__c, Case_Ref__c, OwnerId, 
        Owner.Name FROM Case WHERE Id IN: casesIds 
     AND RecordType.DeveloperName IN: 
     caseRecordTypes]);
    }
    //System.debug('allCasesMap'+allCasesMap);
    List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> mails = new 
      List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>();
    if(!listofTasks.isEmpty()){
        String htmlBody = '';
        htmlBody += 'The below Tasks are due in 1 week: 
         '+'</br></br>';
        htmlBody += '<table border="1" style="border. 
       collapse: collapse"><tr><th>SF Case Ref</th>. 
      <th>Case Subject</th><th>Case Manager</th>. 
     <th>Client Name</th><th>Sub Product</th><th>Task 
      Subject</th><th>Due Date</th><th> Ref</th></tr>';
        for(Task taskReminders : listofTasks){
            
    if(allCasesMap.containsKey(taskReminders.WhatId)){
                Case aCases = 
   allCasesMap.get(taskReminders.WhatId); 
                htmlBody += '<tr>';
                htmlBody += '<td><a 


href="'+URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toExternalForm()+'/'+a. 
       Cases.Id+'">' + aCases.CaseNumber +'</a></td>';
                htmlBody += '<td>'+ ((aCases.Subject != null) ? 
  aCases.Subject : '') +'</td>';
                htmlBody += '<td>'+ ((aCases.OwnerId != null) ? 
  aCases.Owner.Name : '') +'</td>';
                htmlBody += '<td>'+ ((aCases.ContactId != null) ? 
  aCases.Contact.Name : '') +'</td>';
                htmlBody += '<td>'+ ((aCases.Sub_Product__c != 
  null) ? aCases.Sub_Product__c : '') +'</td>';
                htmlBody += '<td>'+ ((taskReminders.Subject != 
 null) ? taskReminders.Subject : '') +'</td>';
                htmlBody += '<td>'+ 
  ((taskReminders.ActivityDate != null) ? 
 String.valueof(taskReminders.ActivityDate) : '') +'</td>';
                htmlBody += '<td>'+ ((aCases.Case_Ref__c != 
 null) ? aCases.Case_Ref__c : '') +'</td>';
                htmlBody += '</tr>';
            }
        }
        htmlBody += '</table>'+'</br></br>';
        htmlBody += 'Note: This is an automated e mail';
        Reminders_for_Tasks__c reminderTask = new 
     Reminders_for_Tasks__c();
        try{
            reminderTask = 
    Reminders_for_Tasks__c.getOrgDefaults();
        }catch(Exception ex){
            System.debug('Exception:'+ex.getMessage());
        }
        Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new 
  Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
        List<String> sendTo = new List<String>();
        for(user aEmailRecipient : userList){
            sendTo.add(aEmailRecipient.Email);
        }
       
        
        mail.setToAddresses(sendTo);
        mail.setSubject(' Task Due in 1 Week');
        

        System.debug('reminderTask:'+reminderTask.From_Sender__c);
         if(reminderTask.From_Sender__c != null){
               mail.setReplyTo(reminderTask.From_Sender__c);
          }
              mail.setHtmlBody(htmlBody);
              mails.add(mail);
        }
              System.debug('mails'+mails);
             if(!mails.isEmpty()){
             Messaging.SendEmailResult[] results = 
               Messaging.sendEmail(mails,false);
              for(Messaging.SendEmailResult oneResult : results){
                  if(!oneResult.isSuccess()){
                
   
   
   
System.debug('SendEmailResult:'+oneResult.getErrors().get(0).getMessage());
                }
           }
        }
   }
  /*finish Method*/
   global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC) {
    
   }
  }
```

Comment: Two questions, can you share your existing batch code and why do you need to split the emails up at all? Why only display 25 in each email?

Comment: Split emails - that's the requirement

Comment: @nbrown  here is the batch code, split email is for end user convenience and manageability.

Comment: The easiest thing that comes to mind is to order your query results by recipient. That way you can build lists of Tasks for the recipient and keep a count of how many Tasks are in the list for purposes of sending out emails.